# How to verify if the image in Selenium using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How would I verify the image is displaying is the correct path/name in Selenium using WebDriver?

I started using this code but not sure :

```
string _active = "<img style="display: ;" alt="Active" src="../App_Themes/Default/images/check.png"/>";
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddeCardControl1_gv']/tbody/tr[11]/td[7]/img")).Text.Contains(_active);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to clarify to you that this code

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddeCardControl1_gv']/tbody/tr[11]/td[7]/img")).Text.Contains(_active);`

does not give you the html code for the image tag but a `IWebElement` object. And you can read the various attributes of this `WebElement` by using the [GetAttribute](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) method.

You will have to get the `src` attribute of the `img` tag you are looking for by locating the image(webelement) by xpath and then

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Your xpath"));
        string path = element.GetAttribute("src");
```

Now you can verify the path of your image. Hope this helps you.